# Структура и ограничение new()

Tags: c#

1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Делаем вот так:

```
public struct mySTRUCT
{
    public c(){}
}
```

Компилятор ругается, всё верно

[CS0568] Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors

4) Делаем обобщённый класс с указанием new()

```
public class myCLASS<T> where T : new () {}
```

А так же делаем обычнуб структуру

```
public struct mySTRUCT{}
```

А теперь делаем вот так:

```
var q = new myCLASS<mySTRUCT>();
```

Компилируем и получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть я повесил ограничение на запрет отсутствия пустого конструктора у типа, при этом забросил тип структура, который не может иметь пустого конструктора, а получил успех??????

В чём тут магия, почему компилятор не ругается?)

Comment: перепутал определение конструктора в пункте 2 при написании вопроса, должно быть  public mySTRUCT(){} 
но суть от этого не меняется

Comment: для исправления нужно использовать не комментарии, а кнопку Править внизу вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типы значений (структурные типы) по умолчанию содержат конструктор без параметров.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

> Если не предоставить конструктор для структуры, C# будет использовать неявный конструктор по умолчанию, чтобы автоматически инициализировать каждое поле типа значения значением по умолчанию.